# CS50 Pset1 (Cash) Compile Bug

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote the whole pset1 (cash) code and it worked just fine before the IDE exchange, but now, with the new VSCode + CS50 IDE i think that maybe the check50 and submit50 commands are bugged.

When i compile the code via terminal it works fine again, but when i check it i receive this message:

":( cash.c compiles
code failed to compile"

This is my code with the new pset1 page requeriments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int change;
    do
    {
        change = get_int("Change: ");
    }
    while(change < 0);

    if(change == 0)
    {
        printf("You'll need 0 coins!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int c = change;
        int x = 0;
        while(c >= 25)
        {
            c -= 25;
            x++;
        }

        while(c >= 10)
        {
            c -= 10;
            x++;
        }

        while(c >= 5)
        {
            c -= 5;
            x++;
        }

        while(c >= 1)
        {
            c -= 1;
            x++;
        }

        printf("You'll need at least %i coins!\n", x);
    }
}
```

And this was my code with the old pset1 requeriments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float change;
    do
    {
        change = get_float("Change: ");
    }
    while(change < 0);

    if(change == 0)
    {
        printf("You'll need 0 coins!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int c = round(change * 100);
        int x = 0;
        while(c >= 25)
        {
            c -= 25;
            x++;
        }

        while(c >= 10)
        {
            c -= 10;
            x++;
        }

        while(c >= 5)
        {
            c -= 5;
            x++;
        }

        while(c >= 1)
        {
            c -= 1;
            x++;
        }

        printf("You'll need at least %i coins!\n", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by IDE exchange? Why does your code need to change?

Comment: If you have questions about the CS50 tools, [cs50.se] seems like a better place to ask.

Comment: Does the IDE really give the ungrammatical message *":( cash.c compiles code failed to compile"?* Does it really output the sad face smiley? And nothing more informative?

Comment: Your new code compiles and links without error or warning (good). Are you sure you didn't do something to lose the `-lcs40` option that links with the CS50 library? Add the exact error you are getting - more than `"...code failed to compile"`.

Comment: The CS50 course uses its own cloud based IDE, and it was changed this year to another one in colaboration with VSCode. When i was using the old IDE the algorithm worked just fine, but now it gives me this error. It does have a command called "check50" in the terminal to see if all the requirements of the exercise were done. When you runs this command it literaly puts this sad face smiley as the error if you had one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE is not the only thing that changed for 2022. The code posted above does *not* meet the "new" requirements. Be sure you are using the [2022 courseware](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/). From the [spec for cash](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/cash/)

> CS50x 2022’s version of Cash is quite different than CS50x 2021’s version. It will be in your best interest to do this problem from scratch, if you do not have credit for the work you did in 2021. Last year’s version will fail to compile when checked by `check50` due to the fact that in this new version, you must implement functions which the testing suite will test independently, beyond just checking for the final answer (as last year’s version did).

Comment: So this "failed to compile" error is because of this? Cause i think that even with the requeriment change, the command check50 would compile and inform me that the steps weren't done, no?

Comment: Man i just realized that they had this new file to download and it makes me creat 5 whole new functions to this simple problem, thats crazy dude, totally unnecessary